# How Do I Add Background Thread To Silverlight Custom Control?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, expression-blend, windows-phone-7.1

I'm building a custom control for Windows Phone 7+ that can do augmented reality image processing. The control works wonderfully in practice (when I run the app), but because I have the image processing running on a separate thread, it breaks when I try to open the page in Blend or the Visual Studio designer.

Here's an example of the thread I'm trying to run (basically taken from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202982(v=vs.92).aspx) :

```
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    // assigning template stuff, initializing my camera

    _myManualResetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(true);
    _myCameraProcessingThread = new System.Threading.Thread(ProcessingMethod);
    _myCameraProcessingThread.Start();
}

void ProcessingMethod()
{
    int[] myBuffer = new int[640 * 480];
    while(_someCondition)
    {
        _myManualResetEvent.WaitOne();
        _myCamera.GetPreviewBufferArgb32(myBuffer);
        // do my processing stuff
        _myManualResetEvent.Set();
    }
}
```

This breaks the ever-loving heck out of Blend. Would love to know why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you are doing a lot of run-time stuff in the `OnApplyTemplate` method.

This will get called when Blend or Visual Studio instantiates the design view of your control.

You should either check to see if you are in design mode using the [`DesignMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component.designmode.aspx):

```
if (!DesignMode)
{
    _myManualResetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(true);
    _myCameraProcessingThread = new System.Threading.Thread(ProcessingMethod);
    _myCameraProcessingThread.Start();
}
```

or move this code into a method/event handler that only gets called when the application actually runs.

Comment: Thanks! That was my problem. If I can ask a follow-up... which methods/event handlers get called when the application runs?

Comment: @MatthiasS - there's the `Loaded` event for one. Check [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189018(v=vs.95).aspx) for more information on Silverlight events.